# MPMoviePlayerController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, clarity

I have a problem with `MPMoviePlayerController` in iPhone device. It is playing in my iPhone device without clarity(cant see the video content properly ). However It is playing in my simulator properly.

Can any one tell me a way to fix this problem..

Comment: You should try to explain the issue a little better. Maybe a screenshot will help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aaa" ofType:@"mp4"];  
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)]; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
[moviePlayerController play];
```